# How to access a model property from seperate javascript file? (MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Right now I am using a model property in the javascript as one of the values in  a json object that i pass to the controller. The problem is that the javascript will be seperated in a .js file and will not be able to access @Model. So the question is; how do i access model from a seperated .js file?

Comment: A workaround is to create javascript variable in your view and access in js file:

`<script>
var varWithValue = '@Model.Value';
</script>`

And access the **varWithValue** in your js file.

Comment: @GeneR It was on my suggestion the user asked, so I feel partly responsible. Is there an alternative way to access the page's model? Or is the *@Model.Blopp* the only choice?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [RazorJs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorJS/) (unfortunatelly seems no more mantained)

> Write Razor-Style C# or VB.NET inside your Javascript Files. Also
>   contains an http handler for serving, when needed, those files.

You could do something like [**this**](https://bitbucket.org/InferOn/razorjs-test/downloads):

---

**Views/Home**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@Html.RazorJSInclude("~/Scripts/App/TestRazorJS.js")
<button id="btnSearch" name="submit" type="button" onclick="LoadFromRazor()">Search</button>
```

---

**Scripts / App / TestRazorJS.js**

```
function LoadFromRazor() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Test", "Home")',
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function () { console.log('done'); },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(status);

        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load the external javascript as usual and the send the model value as a property to an init method like this in your view:

```
<script type="text/url" src="externalscript.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var model = home.views();
            model.init({
                modelProperty: '@Model.Property',
            });
</script>
```

And then your externalscript.js looks like:

```
(function (window) {
    home = window.home || {};
    home.views = function () {
        pub.init = function (options) {
            var property = options.modelProperty;
        };
        return pub;
})(window);
```

And you can use your property like you want to in the external script.